# StackOverflowException causes Google Chome to hang

Tags: .net, google-chrome, iis, stack-overflow

I have a recurring problem, albeit a rare one, whereby if I encounter a `StackOverflowException` when attempting to view a locally hosted page in Google Chrome, it seizes to load the page even after a fix has been applied.

I've tried clearing the Google Chrome DNS cache, done an `iisreset` and `ipconfig /flushdns`, but nothing seems to work. I know the fix is working as the page loads in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Have you tried clearing chrome's cache?

Comment: @PinnyM Apologies; that was the cache I was referring to. I've also done an `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: Not only the DNS cache, you need to flush the page cache as well